# Change values in formula based on data validation selection

Tags: excel, validation, if-statement, excel-formula, dropdown

[My workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/preview/Test/Test.xlsx?role=personal)

I have a spreadsheet that consists of a series of drop-down options. **How do I change the values of a certain formula if an option is selected?**

For example, if a user selects *Not Applicable*, the weighted average should change.  If I have 4 questions, each with a value of **25%**, this should change when the user selects *Not Applicable* for one question.  The weighted average will then need to be **33.333333%** since there are only *3* questions that should be weighted.  If the user selects *Not Applicable* for 2 questions, the weighted average should be **50%** for the remaining questions.

**EXAMPLE:**

User doesn't select *Not Applicable*:

```
Question | Answer         | Weighted Average
   1     | Choice         | 25%
   2     | Choice         | 25%
   3     | Choice         | 25%
   4     | Choice         | 25%
```

User selects *Not Applicable* on one question:

```
Question | Answer         | Weighted Average
   1     | Not Applicable | -
   2     | Choice         | 33.333333%
   3     | Choice         | 33.333333%
   4     | Choice         | 33.333333%
```

User selects *Not Applicable* on two questions:

```
Question | Answer         | Weighted Average
   1     | Not Applicable | -
   2     | Choice         | 50%
   3     | Not Applicable | -
   4     | Choice         | 50%
```

Below is the formula that I am currently using:

`=IF(OR(D39="Yes",D39="Yes - Corrected"),0.25,"")`

Comment: This could really benefit from sample data and expected results.

Comment: You may be able to leverage the `AVERAGEIF` function in Excel, but without seeing your actual file, it's difficult to be 100% sure based solely upon your description.  If you can share a sample file demonstrating the problem, I'm confident we can come up with a solution.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/preview/Test/Test.xlsx?role=personal

Comment: I have added the test document to the dropbox link above.

Comment: My excel is currently running a long solver so I can't work this out as an answer, but my intuition is telling me you could make the formula by instead of putting in .25 as you have done do something like `1/(4 - Countif(Range, "Not Applicable"))`  Not sure off the top of my head how the quotes would work in the countif function or if it needs an equals sign without excel to tell me I messed up but I hope that's kind of what you need.

Comment: I did this but did not recognize.  Giving a NAME error message.  So my formula now looks like this: =IF(OR(D39="Yes",D39="Yes - Corrected"),1/(4 - COUNTIF(Range, "Not Applicable")),"")

Comment: Ok.  If I have other options for example "Not Compliant" that should not be worth a percentage (.25) but should still be included in the weighted average, how do I add this to the formula?

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(B3 = "Not Applicable", "", 1/(4 - (COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6, "Not Applicable"))))`

Just change the cells to be where you need them to be.  This worked for me.

Comment: Ok. If I have other options for example "Not Compliant" that should not be worth a percentage (.25) but should still be included in the weighted average, how do I add this to the formula?

Comment: @user9425493 what are the option you are having..First you said Not Applicable now you are adding few more stuffs..

Comment: So if I have 4 questions (3 says Yes but 1 says Not Compliant) the score should reflect 75% instead of 100%

Comment: Here is my drop down (Yes, Yes - Corrected, Not Compliant, Not Applicable, Not Checked) Not compliant should not give them .25

Comment: Your formula works perfectly @Evan Callahan just need to make the correction to (Not Compliant)

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your Question correctly this the Answer you are looking for

`=IF(B2="Not Applicable","",1/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$5,"<>Not Applicable"))`

Formula in Column `C`

[image]